# Wpdb->query result show 1 but is not an integer

Tags: wp-query, database

I have a weird result. I'm trying to add a column in an existing table. When I check the result *$res*, I have a result like 1 but seems to be not an integer.

**php code**

```
$res = $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE " . $table_name. " ADD " . $column_name . " varchar(35)");
error_log( $res );
error_log( "int ? : " . ( is_int( $res ) ? 'true' : 'false' ) );
```

**output**

```
 1 [18-Dec-2017 16:32:02 UTC] 1

 2 [18-Dec-2017 16:32:02 UTC] int ? : false
```

The column is created. I have a problem only with the returned result to continue my program.
Someone knows why ?

Comment: What is the column's type? Columns not used as keys or indices are probably going to be `varchar`, which is a string type.

Comment: Yes, the column type is varchar. Does that mean $wpdb->query can return a result different than an integer or false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
The result 1 for my query means true and it's a boolean so

> $wpdb->query can return true, not only int|false as it is written above the public function query : [wpdb::query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/)

**PHP code**

```
$res = $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE " . $table_name. " ADD " . $column_name . " varchar(35)");
error_log( $res );
error_log( "bool ? : " . ( is_int( $res ) ? 'true' : 'false' ) );'false' ) );
```

**output**

```
1 [18-Dec-2017 17:10:10 UTC] 1

2 [18-Dec-2017 17:10:10 UTC] bool ? : true
```